# How can I get jscs to use the --fix option from grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jscs

Using grunt-jscs, I'd like to have it use the --fix option to automatically reformat code. How can I pass the command-line option to jscs? I've tried adding args & options, but can't get it to work.

My gruntfile has:

```
jscs: {
    all: {
        src: [
            '*.js',
        ]
    },
    options: {
        config: "/path/to/.jscsrc",
    }
},
```

Comment: is that even an option in jscs? http://jscs.info/overview.html#cli

Comment: Yes - JSCS v1.12.0 https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/releases/tag/v1.12.0 and https://medium.com/@addyosmani/auto-formatting-javascript-code-style-fe0f98a923b8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fix option](https://github.com/jscs-dev/grunt-jscs#fix) is available in grunt-jscs as of v1.8.0.

Specify it like this:

```
jscs: {
  src: "path/to/files/*.js",
  options: {
    fix: true,
    config: ".jscsrc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a popular request for the package author, and is not currently available...

https://github.com/jscs-dev/grunt-jscs/issues/82

perhaps soon though https://github.com/jscs-dev/grunt-jscs/pull/84

Comment: Yes. I've just seen this pull request.